# How does [ ɕ ] ( し) differ from [ ʃ ] ("she")?

Tags: pronunciation

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katakana#Table_of_katakana), the 'sh' sound in Japanese し is pronounced [ɕ] *(in [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet))* while the 'sh' sound in English "she" is pronounced [ʃ].

How do these differ?  I've been pronouncing them exactly the same.

Comment: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24704/native-pronunciation-of-the-character-%E3%81%97

Comment: While you're at it, keep in mind that ち and じ type sounds differ from their English counterparts similarly -- and good on you for trying to learn the difference; otherwise fluent speakers using the English sound is pretty grating IMO.

Comment: http://web.uvic.ca/ling/resources/ipa/charts/IPAlab/IPAlab.htm Samples on this page sound pretty much right. You can check it out yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oooh! Good question. I haven't thought about it in some time, but the Japanese sound is pronounced (at least in my experience in Tokyo) with the tip of the tongue closer to the top front teeth, as in the Mandarin *xi* sound. The way I pronounce English "she" as a native speaker is with air over the middle-front of my tongue, not the tip.

As it so happens, the *Edokko* accent pronounces *hito* like *shito*; this may offer you a way to approach the *shi* sound in standard Japanese (if you have *hi* covered). You can try aspirating *hi* more strongly until you get closer to a *shi* sound that passes muster.